# Compare Devarim 14:11 and Devarim 14:20- Is there a difference in meaning between "tzipor" and "of"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, hebrew, parashat-reeh, birds

The two verses  [Devarim 14:11 and 14:20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=182) appear to say the same thing except that v 11 uses the word "tzipor" and v 20 uses the word "of". Aren't they the same thing? If yes, what is the second verse teaching us that was left out of the first verse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rashi (on the two verses) says that the first is a reference to the [bird of the Metzorah](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9915#showrashi=true&v=7) which is sent away live. It can be subsequently eaten and doesn't become forbidden as something used in the temple service.

The second adds a violation of a positive commandment to the already existing negative commandment about eating non-Kosher birds (there is another verse that does the same for non-Kosher animals).

So yes, they are repetitive, but the first one uses the word Tzippor to refer to a specific kind of bird to permit something additional.